# How to register a device on FCMDevice of fcm-django?

Tags: python, django, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, pyfcm

I'm a beginner at Django.

Referring to this link, I installed fcm-django and finished setting.
[fcm-django doc](https://fcm-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

- Install `fcm-djagno`.

```
pip install fcm-django
```

- Setting `fcm-django` on **`settings.py`**.

```py
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials

cred_path = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "serviceAccountKey.json")
cred = credentials.Certificate(cred_path)
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)

...

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'fcm_django',
]

...

FCM_DJANGO_SETTINGS = {
    # default: _('FCM Django')
    "APP_VERBOSE_NAME": "django_fcm",
    # Your firebase API KEY
    "FCM_SERVER_KEY": "AAAAsM1f8bU:APA91bELsdJ8WaSy...",
    # true if you want to have only one active device per registered user at a time
    # default: False
    "ONE_DEVICE_PER_USER": False,
    # devices to which notifications cannot be sent,
    # are deleted upon receiving error response from FCM
    # default: False
    "DELETE_INACTIVE_DEVICES": True,
}
```

And, when I post notice, if push is active, I try to send push notifications to all devices.

```py
from firebase_admin.messaging import Message, Notification
from fcm_django.models import FCMDevice

class noticeCreateView(View):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        title = request.POST.get('title')
        content = request.POST.get('content')
        push = request.POST.get('push')

        if push:
            message = Message(
                notification=Notification(
                    title=title,
                    body=sentence,
                ),
            )

            try:
                devices = FCMDevice.objects.all()
                devices.send_message(message)
            except Exception as e:
                print('Push notification failed.', e)

        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('notice_list'))
```

What I am curious about is whether data is automatically added in the FCMDevice model when the user installs this app.

If I have to generate data manually, I wonder how to get an FCM registration token and how to implement adding data to the FCMDevice model.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue for a while and found a way to fix this.
after all configurations of django-fcm, when the user login/signup create a device instance of FCMDevice and save user to that instance.

refer [pyrebase](https://github.com/thisbejim/Pyrebase) for creating registration_id(token)

IN VIEWS
from fcm_django.models import FCMDevice

```
fcm_device = FCMDevice()
fcm_device.registration_id = registration_id
fcm_device.user = user
fcm_device.save()
```

[for more reference](https://www.navin.sh/setting-up-platform-independent-push-notifications-with-django-and-firebase)